# trim() method for linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, trim

I have a question, I've looked around on the internet but couldn't find an example. But making a String trim() method in java (remove lead/trailing whitespace), I know the basic code for this is:

```
    public LString trim(){
    int i = this.size;
    int j = 0;
    int k = this.offset;
    char[] arrayOfChar = this.data;
    while ((j < i) && (arrayOfChar[(k + j)] <= ' '))
      ++j;
    while ((j < i) && (arrayOfChar[(k + i - 1)] <= ' '))
      --i;
    return (((j > 0) || (i < this.size)) ? substring(j, i) : this);
}
```

*But, how would you write this same method, but applied to a linked list? More specifically, a linked list that uses a Node class.*

Here is what I did....correct me if this is wrong...I'll include relevant class information that pertains to the question.

```
public class LString{

   private Node front = null;  //first val in list
   private Node back;   //last val in list
   private int size = 0;
   private int i;
   private int offset;

   public LString(){
      //construct empty list
      Node LString = new Node();
      front = null;

   }
.......//skip down some methods to this one

   //returns new lstring that is slice of lstring
   //contains an endIndex as well
   public LString substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex){
      Node current = this.front;
      int size = 0;
      while(current != null && size < beginIndex){
         size++;
         current = current.getNext();
      }
      front = new Node();
      front.setData(current.getData());
      Node ocurrent = front;

      while(current != null && size < endIndex){
         current = current.getNext();
         Node curr2 = new Node();
         curr2.setData(current.getData());

         ocurrent.setNext(curr2);
         ocurrent = curr2;
         size++;
      }    
      ocurrent.setNext(null);    //set next val to null to term string
      return this;
   }

   public LString trim(){
      String lstr;
      int i = this.size;
      int m = this.offset;
      int k = charAt(m);
      Node current = front;
      while(current != null){
         current = current.getNext();
         if(current.data > '\u0020'){
         return this;
         } else if(current.data < '\u0020'){
            LString lstring = new LString();    //this worked!?
            return lstring;
           }
      }
      return this.substring(k, m+1);
   }
```

...............................................................

```
//My Node class:


public class Node{
   public char data;
   public Node next;

   //constructors from page 956
   public Node()
   {
      this('\0',null);  //'\0' is null char for java
   }

   public Node(char initialData, Node initialNext)
   {
      data = initialData;
      next = initialNext;
   }
   }
```

(If you are unfamiliar with the node class, it basically just creates a singly linked node to use as your links between data in your linked list class)

I've never seen an example or anything, so I thought I'd ask the community.

Comment: That data in the Node is going to be of the type String and you'll call the trim method on that String.

Comment: Can you provide an example about what are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

- by trimming the list you want to remove leading and trailing elements that are null
- and under *"linked list that uses a Node class"* you mean [java.util.LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

You should keep in mind that in java internal implementation of LinkedList is not exposed (note: *java.util.LinkedList.Node* has *private* access modifier), all modifications are performed through methods of iterator and LinkedList itself.

Implementation would be:

```
public static void trim (LinkedList list){
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0) return;

    Object element = null;

    ListIterator i = list.listIterator();
    while (i.hasNext() && element == null) {
        element = i.next();
        if (element == null) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }

    element = null;
    i = list.listIterator(list.size());
    while (i.hasPrevious() && element == null) {
        element = i.previous();
        if (element == null) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

**However if you are reimplementing mutable strings via linked list as an exercise**
(if not as an exercise then stop right there and use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)), then, assuming that you implement it with doubly linked list, it will go like this:

**EDIT:** my bad, you can iterate to the first non-empty element and set reference directly to it, updated algorithm

> 1. Fetch first element
> 2. While fetched element is empty fetch next
> 3. Set *head* reference to the last fetched element, set last fetched element's *prev* reference to null
> 4. Fetch last element
> 5. While fetched element is empty fetch previous
> 6. Set tail reference to the last fetched element, set last fetched element's *next* reference to null

**UPDATE** With code you provided try something like this (since you are using singly-linked list, it is slightly different then the one described above):

```
public void trim(){
    //early out if empty
    if (front == null || back==null) return;

    Node current = front;

    //looking for the first non-empty element
    while(current != null && current.data<'\u0020' ){
        current = current.next;
    }

    //left trim
    this.front = current;

    //looking for last non-empty element
    while (current!=null&&current.next!=null&&current.next.data>'\u0020'){
        current = current.next;
    }

    //right trim
    this.back = current;
    if (current!=null){
        current.next = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to trim each String in a LinkedList, why not just iterate over each item?

```
LinkedList<String> myNodes = new LinkedList<String>();
myNodes.add('This is a node ');
myNodes.add(' another node    '));

for (String s : myNodes){
  s.trim();
}
```